# Program to reverse a number in array

Tags: java

When I try the following code it gives right answer. But when I try to use `a.length` it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. How to make my code to use `a.length`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a;

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    a = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i = a.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no element in `a` at the index `a.length`, because index range of a will be from `0 to (a.length - 1)`. Since there is no index, that will throw the Exception.

Comment: I have answered your question @Nisha please see to it if you are weak in using for loops .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] a;


  int n=sc.nextInt();
  a=new int[n];

  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) // Remove = from for loop
    {
    a[i]=sc.nextInt();
  }

  for(int i = a.length - 1; i>0; i--) // Modify here 
  {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
  }

 } 
}
```

Or for reverse an array you can use directly as below :

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 5):

there is no element in `a` at the index `a.length`, because index range of `a` will be from `0 to (a.length - 1)`. Since there is no index, that will throw the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can only iterate through a.length-1 since the index position start with 0. so in the above case do the below change and it would work as required

```
  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
    a[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of String functions in JAVA . The StringBuffer class is like a dynamic string with awesome built in methods .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = sc.nextInt();

  String num = String.valueOf(n);
  StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(num);
  StringBuffer revNum = b.reverse();
  String rev = revNum.toString();
  int reversedNumber = Integer.parseInt(rev);

  System.out.println(reversedNumber);

}
```

Comment: I tried to execute the code and when I did it print just that number.Will I need to add for loop to enter 3 or more numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0; i<=a.length; i++)  // let say a.length=5; 
        {                          // by default all the element start from 
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();        //index zero in array 0 1 2 3 4
    }                            //so there is nothing like a[5]
                                // that's why you are getting arrayOutOfBound 
    for(int i=a.length; i>=0; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
```